# Extracting geometry / location keys from Google API JSON in Python 3: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, python-3.6, simplejson

I am geocoding with JSON as output and then want to extract geometry : location keys to store the lat | lng information for subsequent visualization. I get the error message

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

I did not find answer on stack overflow or the simplejson website. I would appreciate guidance on errors in my syntax. Thank you!
PS. I removed google api key to avoid $$. I hope you have one handy if you are willing to run the code and identify the error that way.

> import googlemaps
>
> import pprint
>
> import simplejson as json
>
> from datetime import datetime
>
> gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='insert a google API key')
>
> ## Geocoding an address
>
> geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
>
> pprint.pprint(geocode_result)
>
> python_conversion=json.load(geocode_result.read())
>
> geo_input=json.dumps([s['geometry']['location'] for s in 
>   python_conversion['address_components']], indent=3)
>
> pprint.pprint(geo_input)
>
> > The first part of the code yields this JSON:

[{'address_components': [{'long_name': '1600',
                          'short_name': '1600',
                          'types': ['street_number']},
                         {'long_name': 'Amphitheatre Parkway',
                          'short_name': 'Amphitheatre Pkwy',
                          'types': ['route']},
                         {'long_name': 'Mountain View',
                          'short_name': 'Mountain View',
                          'types': ['locality', 'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'Santa Clara County',
                          'short_name': 'Santa Clara County',
                          'types': ['administrative_area_level_2',
                                    'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'California',
                          'short_name': 'CA',
                          'types': ['administrative_area_level_1',
                                    'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'United States',
                          'short_name': 'US',
                          'types': ['country', 'political']},
                         {'long_name': '94043',
                          'short_name': '94043',
                          'types': ['postal_code']}],
  'formatted_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA',
  'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 37.4217407, 'lng': -122.0832867},
               'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
               'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.4230896802915,
                                          'lng': -122.0819377197085},
                            'southwest': {'lat': 37.4203917197085,
                                          'lng': -122.0846356802915}}},
  'place_id': 'ChIJhehRjJ-5j4ARKFssUSrwnhY',
  'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'CWC8+RP Mountain View, California, United '
                                 'States',
                'global_code': '849VCWC8+RP'},
  'types': ['street_address']}]

> The second part, where I extract the geo coordinates is where I get the stated error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do for Google Places:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang
YOUR_API_KEY = 'Get an API key from google'


google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        location='Manhattan', keyword='Coffee')#,
        #radius=200000)#, types=[types.TYPE_HEALTH])

if query_result.has_attributions:
    print (query_result.html_attributions)

station_names=[]
station_locs=[]
station_ids=[]
ct=0
for place in query_result.places:
    # Returned places from a query are place summaries.
    station_names.append(place.name)
    ct+=1
    station_locs.append(place.geo_location)
    station_ids.append(place.place_id)

    # The following method has to make a further API call.
    place.get_details()
    # Referencing any of the attributes below, prior to making a call to
    # get_details() will raise a googleplaces.GooglePlacesAttributeError.
    #print (place.details) # A dict matching the JSON response from Google.
    #print (place.local_phone_number)
    #print (place.international_phone_number)
    #print (place.website)
    #print (place.url)


#ct=0
# Are there any additional pages of results?
while( query_result.has_next_page_token and ct<200):
    ct+=1
    query_result_next_page = google_places.nearby_search(
            pagetoken=query_result.next_page_token)
    print("more pages")
    for place in query_result_next_page.places:
        station_names.append(place.name)
        station_locs.append(place.geo_location)

station_tuples=[]
for p in station_locs:
    station_tuples.append((float(p['lat']),float(p['lng'])))
```